# choose relevent length of interval

Tags: calculus, analysis, definite-integrals

i have question related to   Riemann sum. Is then  length of interval matters? Suppose we want to calculate  Riemann  net sum of function

$f(x)=3-x/2$  in this interval $[2,14]$. 
I first take $n=2$, so that i would have   $(14-2)/2=6$, so we would have following values  $8,14$, so in total we would have  $6(f(6)+f(14))=6(3-3+3-7)=6(-4)=-24$,
so it means that  we should take  absolute value and  get $24$. Is  this correct ? if this represent  as a definite integral, then we can say that width of each is equal to $12/n$, and starting from $3$, we would have points  $2+12/n$, $2+24/n$ and so on. Now we should put this value into function yes? but how? i am confused  in this point,do we have

$12/n(f(2+12/n)+f(2+24/n)....f(14))$? and taking limit? it seems time confusing

Comment: Why did you delete your other question? I was writing an answer for the one you deleted

Comment: sorry for this, could  this integral be negative?

Comment: you are (at least the question implies this) not interessted in the integral, but in the area below the graph, so you integrate the absolute value of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity that you are using is as follows:
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf\left(a+\frac{b-a}{n}i\right)\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)$$ In this equality, we can set the right point in any sub-interval just to compute the wight of the boxes. The function $f(x)=3-x/2$ is continuous on $[2,14]$, so we can speak about above summation and so about the definite integral on this interval. You put $n=\color{red}{2}$ so you got the following summation: $$f\left(2+\frac{14-2}{\color{red}{2}}\right)\frac{14-2}{\color{red}{2}}+f\left(8+\frac{14-2}{\color{red}{2}}\right)\frac{14-2}{\color{red}{2}}=(f(8)+f(14))\times 6$$ See below:

[image]

But this summation with two terms gives us a very bad approximation for the definite integral, so as you noted we consider $n$ sub-interval. Indeed, we need to have a summation like above. I mean:

$$A=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf\left(2+\frac{12}{n}i\right)\left(\frac{12}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(2-\frac{6}{n}i\right)(12/n)$$ The length of interval does matter, cause we put it inside the $f$ as a part. In fact it plays an important role in doing the summation and taking the limit after that.

[image]

Comment: so does it means that interval length does not matter?

Comment: but how sum,it takes  messy calculation

Comment: @dato: Nope :-) Put $12/n$ away and do the summation. It is $$\sum_{i=1}^n (2-6i/n)=\sum_{i=1}^n 2-(6/n)\sum_{i=1}^n i$$

Comment: so it is equal lim(2n-6/n*(n(n+1)/2))?

Comment: @dato: It is $-12(n+3)/n$

Comment: so answer is equal to $12$ right?  answer is $-12$,but area should be 12 right?

Comment: @dato: Yes. This is what Dominic pointed.

Comment: is not  simply solution of this problem?

Comment: no mean different one,i know this one before,just  could not i choose some specific  value of $n$?

Comment: for example choose n large,let say 12,because  $14-2=12$

Comment: so at  exams,if choose  some specific value of n,will it be mistake?

Comment: @dato: If you want to examine and get some perspectives of what is going on in the summation, it will be OK. But for finding the area no. You should work on a general rule as I indicated above. :)

Comment: that is what i  have asked,i can't choose some specific value of n,because answer would be wrong for areas right?\

Comment: @dato: Why specific?? Setting an specific value for $n$ such as $n=2$, $n=4$, or even $n=10^{10}$ do not give you the right value.

Comment: so only solution is to take limit,thanks in advance,if there is not mentioned term area?i meant just  find rieman sum?

Comment: @dato: I think so friend. :-)

Comment: and what about situation when  is not asked area,but just sum?

Comment: @dato: Considering this fact that I cannot see your exam question as it 's asked here, I assume yes. You're asked to find just that summation.

Comment: have not seen question?wait a minute

Comment: http://ibsu.edu.ge/Upload/IPS/%E1%83%99%E1%83%9D%E1%83%9B%E1%83%9E%E1%83%98%E1%83%A3%E1%83%A2%E1%83%94%E1%83%A0%E1%83%A3%E1%83%9A%E1%83%98%20%E1%83%9B%E1%83%94%E1%83%AA%E1%83%9C%E1%83%98%E1%83%94%E1%83%A0%E1%83%94%E1%83%91%E1%83%90.pdf  calculus section,question 11

Comment: @dato: You had to find the whole area using this method. It's asked very clearly. Indeed, you're asked to take the limit and find +12.

Comment: if there would be not  net area,but just rieman sum?or  it is a same

Comment: In that time, I assume you have to find just the summation without taking limit.

Comment: @Babak.S,so not to confuse,area and Rieman sum,even  in the last  area is not mentioned,are same

Comment: is this correct?please help me